# writing async Repository methods inside my asp.net mvc5 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application + Entity Framework 6. and I want to have a repository model class inside my application. currently I am following this approach to have async action methods and async repository model class.

for example I have the following repository save method:

```
public class Repository
{
    private Entities t = newEntities();

    public async Task Save()
    {
        await t.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

which I am calling from my action methods as follow:

```
Repository repository = new Repository();
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetResourceByName(string resourcename)
      {
         await  repository.Save();
      }
```

so is this a correct approach? as I am doing the following:

1. I define the repository method as a Task & also the Action method as Task. so should I have both of them as Task(s).?
2. I am using `await` twice on the action method (when calling the repo method) and on the repository? so are these `await` redundant?

//please note that this is only a simple example of a repository method  which is just used to save model,, but I am asking about the approach itself as I will be using this approach in a more complex repository methods ..

Answer (score 2):

1. Q1: Yes both should return Task and that's how it should be and it is completely fine.
2. Q2: Yes both should have the await (if you have more layers, then all those function calls in all those layers should have await).

Basically: Once you go async/await, all the call chain should be async/await to avoid thread related issues...

If you don't await then that is called: "Fire and Forget" which is not recommended, because then this request will be returned to the user with success message, but at a later time, the call that you made without the await could fail and throw an exception and you wont have any idea of what is that exception...

Comment: i am fully aware of the "Fire and Forget".But still i did not get why i need to have an await inside my action method. for example if i replace this "await  repository.Save()" with "repository.Save()//no await" then by defualt asp.net mvc will not continue execution unless it get a result . and since the repo method uses await "await t.SaveChangesAsync();" then it should wait till the save in completed ,, is this correct ? in other word the action method will not continue execution unless the  "await t.SaveChangesAsync();" is complete,,so why i need to await and already awaited method !!

Comment: It's not true. If you dont put await it wont wait and you wouldn't know the outcome of the call...

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to both answers two `awaits` are not necessary. `await` and `async` are only necessary if you need the result from a `Task` before continuing. If you don't need that result then you don't need to mark your method `async`.

This means this method...

```
public async Task Save()
{
    await t.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Can be simplified into

```
public Task Save()
{
    return t.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Even though these are functionally the same, I like the second version because it shows recognition that `Task` is the asynchronous work and async/await are only signals to the compiler to wait for that work to complete.

Comment: Beware that, in case of an exception inside , the stack trace `t.SaveChangesAsync()` will not show `Save()` while if `await` is used it will.

Comment: @Shoe thanks for the reply, you mentioned " If you don't need that result then you don't need to mark your method async." but i think you mean " If you don't need that result then you don't need to mark your method await" ?? is this correct , as await will cause the system to wait for the code to complete before continue ..

Comment: @Shoe "Contrary to both answers two awaits are not necessary". The answers don't say they are "necessary", they say it's not redundant. This is a major difference.

Comment: @johnG marking a method async "unlocks" the await keyword. If you mark a method async but then do not await anything you will get a warning. If you are not awaiting anything then you do not need to mark your method async.

Comment: @Maxime The way I read your answer it implies both methods need to await (and hence need to be async).

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the other answers, here is why you should use `await` and more.

ASP.NET has a synchronization context that will be captured on each `await` and the continuation (the rest of the `async` method) will be posted for that context. That means not only thread switching but populating the switched to thread with the ASP.NET context.

If you suffix your asynchronous calls (those with `await` with a call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` the ASP.NET context switching won't happen (although the thread switching will).

Because the action view engine most probably need the ASP.NET context, you can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the MVC action method. But you should use on all methods called by it.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
public class Repository
{
    private Entities t = new Entities();
    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await t.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}


Repository repository = new Repository();
public async Task<ActionResult> GetResourceByName(string resourcename)
{
    await repository.SaveAsync();
}
```

Because you might not have an ASP.NET context after an `await` with a call to `ConfigureAwait(false)` you should pass as arguments everything you need from the ASP.NET context.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but i did not get ur point why i need to add "ConfigureAwait(false);" inside the SaveAsync ? in my case i am not using it and i did not find any problem,, so if i do not use it what will this cause?

Comment: Please, read [these articles](https://docs.com/paulo-morgado/8860/async-await-general) to learn how `async-await` works.

Comment: so you mean i need to use "ConfigureAwait(false);" ??

Comment: I think you should. But you need to read the articles to know.

Comment: Reentering the request context is a fast operation. ConfigureAwait isn't really needed for asp.net apps. It's purpose is really for building a library that can be targeted by other types of applications.

Comment: As fast as it is, it's not a noop. And it will happen on each and every `await` on not completed awaitables. And for no usable purpose.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes, they should both return Tasks.
2. Yes, the `await` make sense. No, they are not redundant.

To understand why you *might* (not necessary) need to `await` twice, I suggest you take a look at this article which gives a pretty clear example of how and why it works:

[C# async and await: Why Do We Need Them?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2013/12/18/c-async-and-await-why-do-we-need-them-part-1.aspx)

If you want to use repositories and may want to consider using services for you business logic, I would recommend you check this project that is easily extensible and generic:

[URF - Unit of Work & Repositories Framework](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/)

Before you consider developing everything from scratch, you should check it out. I really love this project!

Comment: thanks for the reply you mentioned that i need to use await twice ; on the action method & on the repository. but i am not sure why i need to await an already awaited method.. As since i am await the entities.savechnagesasync() on the repository class, so why i need to use await when calling the already awaited method ?